# How linux knows the name of my hardware?

Tags: linux, hardware

Let's say I run `lspci` command. This command reports names and models of the devices in my system. Output may look like:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 3e)
```

This string "Centrino Ultimate-N 6300" - where it came from? Was it originally stored somewhere inside the network card's ROM? If not, the card must have provided some information which allowed linux kernel to uniquely identify it. What information is that, how can I get it?

Comment: You can use ``strace lsusb`` for detail information.

Comment: @misdeed I like this approach! Not sure I have enough skills to follow it, but I'll work on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names come from the translation of the PCI vendor:device code of the hardware using a local database/text file for the text descriptions.

The file itself is located at `/usr/share/misc/pci.ids`.

In this case you can find, in Debian 9/Stretch in this file:

"Intel Corporation":

```
[line 19280] 8086  Intel Corporation
```

Centrino Ultimate...

```
[line 24449]         422b  Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
```

From the text, your PCI vendor:device code seems to be 8086:422b